# serilog JSON format using original field names

Tags: serilog

Starting from version 3.1.0, TraceId and SpanId have been introduced and are now written in JSON format as @tr and @sp. How can I use TraceId and SpanId directly without using abbreviations? How should I handle this?

Right now, I'm seeing:

```
{
    "time": "2023-12-27T16:05:49.961610672+08:00",
    "@t": "2023-12-27T08:05:49.9614905Z",
    "@mt": "xxxxxx",
    "@tr": "88a772ee01ba9638826404854610b04b",
    "@sp": "baa96aeaf9601eac",
    "ConnectionId": "0HMVS8LGKQ6UQ"
}
```

But I'd like to eimit it like this:

```
{    
    "time": "2023-12-27T16:05:49.961610672+08:00",
    "@t": "2023-12-27T08:05:49.9614905Z",
    "@mt": "xxxxxx",
    "TraceId": "88a772ee01ba9638826404854610b04b",
    "SpanId": "baa96aeaf9601eac",
    "ConnectionId": "0HMVS8LGKQ6UQ"
}
```

Comment: What's the consumption scenario - where are your events being ingested into? Would a solution that writes under new and old names be helpful in your context?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ExpressionTemplate` from the *Serilog.Expressions* package:

```cs
// using Serilog.Templates;

var formatter = new ExpressionTemplate(
    "{ {time: @t, @t, @mt, TraceId: @tr, SpanId: @sp, ..@p} }");
```

I'm not sure where `time` is coming from in your example, the code here assumes that it's intended to be an alias for `@t`.

You haven't mentioned which sink you're using, but the majority accept an `ITextFormatter` argument, which is implemented by `ExpressionTemplate`.

Your example also omits the exception and the level. Check out the [*Serilog.Expressions* README](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions) and also [this blog post](https://nblumhardt.com/2021/06/customize-serilog-json-output/) describing the different JSON formatting options and possibilities.